# Is it possible to export exercises from R/exams to Moodle without listing the options with (a,b,c,d)?

Tags: r, list, moodle, r-exams

Is it possible to export exercises from R/exams to Moodle without listing the options with (a,b,c,d)?
In the image bellow the options with the bullets (a,b,c,d):

[image]

Is it possible to define any option in the `exams2moodle` function that explicitly creates an XML file which after importing to Moodle creates a list without bullets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is controlled by the `answernumbering` argument. The default is `"abc"` but it can also be set to `"ABCD"`, `"123"`, or `"none"`. Thus, for example: `exams2moodle("swisscapital.Rmd", schoice = list(answernumbering = "none"))` in case of a single-choice question.